# jquery file upload behind htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, jquery-file-upload

I have a problem on my website: I've installed the jquery file upload plugin in admin folder containing an htacces file.
    This files contains :

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 60M
php_value post_max_size 60M
php_value max_execution_time 800

AuthUserFile "/path/to/my/htusers"
AuthType Basic
AuthName "ADMIN"
require valid-user
<Files htusers>
deny from all
</Files>
```

The files are uploaded in the upload folder which is outside the admin folder.
The images are displayed but when I click on delete i got this as answer:

> 401 Authorization Required
>  Authorization Required This server
>   could not verify that you are authorized to access the document
>   requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad
>   password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the
>   credentials required.

And after click on delete I have to login again using htaccess.

Did I miss something ?

Someone answered me that the uploaded files had to be under the same htacces that jquery file upload but not better. My files looks like:

```
/
    - admin
        - .htaccess
        - upload
        - plugins
            - jquery file upload
                - ...
```

Files are uploaded into the upload folder.

Edit : maybe the problem comes from the data-url which contains the username :

```
http://admin@localhost/fspva/admin/plugins/jfile_upload/server/php/
?file=../../../../../upload/galerie/23/135x135.jpg&_method=DELETE
```

I tried to set 'access_control_allow_credentials' to false but the URL is the same...

---

The solution is:

For me the problem was the remote user in the url. So I commented the line :

```
//(!empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'].'@' : '').
```

And now the user name doesn't appear anymore in the url and the deletion works even if the upload folder is not under the same htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

For me the problem was the remote user in the url. So I commented the line :

```
//(!empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'].'@' : '').
```

And now the user name doesn't appear anymore in the url and the deletion works even if the upload folder is not under the same htaccess